# node-sass missing vendor folder in all projects

Tags: node-sass, enoent

Hello i have rly serious issues with my nodejs builds and node-sass.

Some weeks ago i had problems with SASS build and node 10 - there were compatibílity problems. As a "best temporary solution" i have installed 2 versions of node.js to my systems - 9 and 10. I have done also some "temporal binding of sass".

Now i have really big issue i cannot build any application where is node-sass used.

I got very typical error:

```
ENONENT: no such file or directory \nativescript\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
```

i have tried everthing..  however.. i have got some strange behavior. When i rebuild node-sass (npm rebuild node-sass --force) i got at the end of log:

```
19 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:28.07
gyp info ok
Installed to D...\NODE-SASS-TEMPORAL\win32-x64-64_binding.node
node-sass@4.9.3 ...\nativescript\node_modules\node-sass

VENDOR folder is really not created in /nativescript/.. folder, however... file "win32-x64-64_binding.node" is created in \NODE-SASS-TEMPORAL\ folder i have created some time ago for a reason i do not remember..

where is that \NODE-SASS-TEMPORAL\ set?

Any ideas?